# Fast muxing of remote HLS using GStreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to download an HLS remote source to a local MKV file. The pipeline is working well but it seems that the download is very slow (no encoding, only re-muxing). 
I would expect the process to be as fast as the network speed but that is not the case. 
Looks like GStreamer is playing the HLS playlist like it was a live playlist, although it's not. The playlist is closed and it's not a live stream.

I'm using `souphttpsrc` as the SRC and `filesink` with local path as the output. 
Also, when running the pipeline I can see in the console the following lines:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'souphttpsrc0': gst.soup.session=context, session=(SoupSession)NULL, force=(boolean)false;
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

I guess `GstSystemClock` has something to do with it (?)

This is the complete pipeline I'm using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=x.mkv souphttpsrc 
location="https://path/to/index.m3u8" ! queue2 max-size-bytes=1000000000 ! 
tee name=t t. ! queue max-size-bytes=1000000000 ! hlsdemux ! tsdemux ! audio/mpeg ! 
aacparse ! mux. t. ! queue max-size-bytes=1000000000 ! hlsdemux ! tsdemux ! 
video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! mux.
```

How can I make GStreamer download and mux as fast as the network enables?

Comment: I would suspect that the remote host is rate limited to save bandwidth in case people abort streaming not having wasted gigabytes of data.

Comment: Not the case. I am in control of the remote host and it's not limited. Downloading using curl is very fast... It's just the gstreamer download that shows poor performance.

Comment: @idan -- Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @GroovyDotCom no. ended up downloading and running the pipeline locally.